# Display button on image in fixed align same in all devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to display 2 buttons in the main image of landing page.
I am trying to add many media queries to make the alignment of the buttons responsive when the device size changes
but still it is not working in all devices.

hear is html file and images zip folder

https://github.com/MiteshKalal7/crushme/tree/main/crushme

link to [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/aged-water-9wuzy?file=/index.html)

please help me the do this.

i will appreciate your efforts for helping me.

i am stuck in this issues in last 2 days.

thank you for helping..

Comment: i tried clicking on the zip file above and couldnt open it, alternatively can you try codesandbox to show your code and output?

Comment: i think the link looks like a spam, your best chance is to add it to github or use codesandbox.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-water-9wuzy?file=/index.html

Comment: @hafizali can you help me?